# How can we implement compare method of comparator class

Tags: java, collections, compare

How can we implement a compare method that compares `Employee`s by their employee Id?

```
public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        if(emp1.getEmpid()<emp2.getEmpid())
        {
            return -1;
        }    
        else if(emp1.getEmpid()>emp2.getEmpid())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
       if(emp1==null || emp1==null ){
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not an Employee instance");
       }
       if(emp1.getEmpid()<emp2.getEmpid()){        
          return -1;
       }    
       else if(emp1.getEmpid()>emp2.getEmpid()){
           return 1;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `instanceof` check is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Your code would be better to understand (especially for newbies) if you add `{...}` around your `return 1;`

Answer (score 0):

remove `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` line from the code.  It is added by your IDE(I think) and it is unnecessary here.